# Implementation of observer pattern with one observer/multiple publishers and multiple events?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, observer-pattern

I'm in a bit of a tricky situation where I need to use the Observer pattern but I don't really know the best way to go about it.

Here's a quick briefing on my application:

I'm implementing a GUI application that allows users to create flowcharts and mindmaps by dropping shapes onto a canvas and then manipulating the shapes by clicking, dragging, and holding. My shapes have the base class type of `MindMapComponentInstance`, and my canvas has type `Canvas`. The `Canvas` object acts as a kind of controller, creating and storing references to all the `MindMapComponentInstance` objects when a user drops onto the canvas.

Now I need to implement mouse event functionality. Specifically, I need the `Canvas` object to "watch" or "listen" to all the mouse events that are registered on the `MindMapComponentInstance` objects. So, basically I have an undefined amount of publishers (the `MindMapComponentInstance` objects), and one subscriber (the `Canvas` object).

To make things slightly more complicated, I need to be able to distinguish between different type of mouse events. A click, drag, hold, etc must all be distinguished by the `Canvas` object, as it needs to act differently depending on the type of mouse event that is registered by the `MindMapComponentInstance` objects.

What is the best way to implement what I need? Will the standard observer pattern suffice? Or should I do things a little differently to result in better code design?

EDIT: I thought I'd mentioned that my application is a web app and as such is being written in javascript, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Observer will work fine here.  You can distinguish between type of clicks with the event parameter that you pass.

What concerns me is that it sounds like `Canvas` is trying to be model, view, and controller all in one.  `Canvas` should have a single responsibility.  If `Canvas` stores instances of `MindMapComponentInstance` it's a model.  If it listens as the user manipulates them it's a controller. If it translates the model to a way to present it's state it's a view.  If it does all three it's a big ball of mud that needs to be broken up.

There are many ways to implement [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [many variations of it](http://deviq.com/kinds-of-models/). Here's [one I find interesting](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

The observer pattern is just a small part of designing a good architecture.  Don't expect simply adding it to fix everything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think you make a good point about the `Canvas` object. `Canvas` is basically acting like a controller and a model. Within the `Canvas` is another object that acts as the view, i.e. does all the rendering and storage of the `MindMapComponentInstance` objects, but the `Canvas` also needs to manipulate them, as my question refers to. Another thing I'm worried is that I have a parent object observing it's children, which seems a little "off" to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with "parents" observing "children" so long as parents don't have to know childish details.  The model doesn't care if it's a image or a text box.  It knows it's moving to 10,15.  What it will look like when it gets there is something else's problem.